# Let's get critical: Nov 2013 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Chess Stack Exchange](http://chess.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://chess.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Final Results

- [How to improve my blitz skills?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/3950/how-to-improve-my-blitz-skills)

  **Net Score: 5** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [What is the reason for using gambits on defence?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/2937/what-is-the-reason-for-using-gambits-on-defence)

  **Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Are two knights generally worth less than two bishops?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/2860/are-two-knights-generally-worth-less-than-two-bishops)

  **Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Multi-threat situation](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/2926/multi-threat-situation)

  **Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Well-annotated books for average players](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/2920/well-annotated-books-for-average-player)

  **Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [How to convert PGN moves to long algebraic notation (in python)?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/2895/how-to-convert-pgn-moves-to-long-algebraic-notation-in-python)

  **Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Why is the king powerless and the queen powerful?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/2909/why-is-the-king-powerless-and-the-queen-powerful)

  **Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [Software for opening repertoire practice](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/3971/software-for-opening-repertoire-practice)

  **Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 7, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Humans against computers](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/3978/humans-against-computers)

  **Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 3)

---

- [Strategy on castle (short or long)](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/3960/strategy-on-castle-short-or-long)

  **Net Score: -3** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 4)

---